# Вставка переменных в DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть строка в обработке данных датафрейма (чистка пустых ячеек)

```
records_clear = (records.loc[records['Style'].notna(), ['Age', 'Style']])
```

Как вместо Style и Age подставить переменные? Пытаюсь сделать через f-string.

```
records_clear = f"(records.loc[records['{style_var}'].notna(), ['{age_var}', '{style_var}']])"
```

Но в таком случае переменная records_clear меняет свой тип на str. Помогите.

Comment: records_clear = (records.loc[records[style_var].notna(), [age_var, style_var]])

Answer (score 1):

просто подставляйте:

```
age_var = 'Age'
records_clear = (records.loc[records['Style'].notna(), [age_var, 'Style']])
```